# OCaml recursive list size function returning incorrect size

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I would assume that this is exactly the code to find the length of a list:

```
let rec size lst =
  match lst with
    | [] -> 0
    | h::t -> 1 + (size t);;
```

But for some reason when I apply it to a list of size 2 it returns 1? I feel like I'm missing some glaring problem but this seems so simple to me.

Comment: I have copied pasted your code - and it gives the right result.

Comment: Ensure you create a list in a correct way. `size [1; 2]` returns `2` for me.

Comment: Please show us the whole code with the list you tried this on. Most probably you made a typo and wrote `[1, 2]` (which is equivalent to `[ (1,2) ]`) instead of `[1; 2]`

Answer (score 4):

The expression `size [1,2]` will return `1` since `[1,2]` is a syntactic sugar for `[(1,2)]`, i.e., it is a list consisting of one pair. Elements of a list are separated by the semicolon `;` in OCaml. So, `size [1;2]` will return `2`.